# let $a-b=6$ and $b\leq-1$ and $a\leq-2$. Find $A=\sqrt{(a+2)^2}+\sqrt{(b+1)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let $a-b=6$ and $b\leq-1$ and $a\leq-2$. Find $A=\sqrt{(a+2)^2}+\sqrt{(b+1)^2}$

***My Try*** $$A=\sqrt{a^2+4a+4}+\sqrt{b^2+2b+1}=$$then I can't

Please just a hint.

Comment: What is the square root of $4^2$? What is the square root of $(-4)^2$? Which case holds for each of the two terms in your question?

Comment: Are you sure it's $a-b=6$, rather than $a+b=6$ or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply write $b$ in terms of $a$ (and mind the conditions on $a$ and $b$:  $a \leq −2$ so $a+2\leq0$ and $b\leq-1$ so $b+1\leq0$) and you get
$$A=\sqrt{(a+2)^2}+\sqrt{(b+1)^2}=\sqrt{(a+2)^2}+\sqrt{(a-6+1)^2}=|a+2| + |a-5|=-a-2-a+5=-2a+3$$
since $a+2\leq0$ and $b+1\leq0$ ($\Rightarrow |a+2| = -a-2 \text{ and } |a-5| = -a-5$).

Comment: $\sqrt {x^2} != \pm x$

Comment: of course!, so there are *4* possible answers!

Comment: Conditions are given on a and b

Comment: @Foga We have $a\leqslant -2$ so $a+2\leqslant 0$ and $b\leqslant -1$ so $b+1\leqslant 0$. Applying those conditions gives one unique answer.

Comment: oh sorry, I've forgotten them...I'll edit..

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
 You need to know that $a\leqslant -2$ iff $a+2\leqslant 0$, and $b\leqslant -1$ iff $b+1\leqslant 0$. And the most important thing: $$ \color{lightblue}{\boxed{\color{white}{\boxed{\color{white}{\overline{\underline{\color{black}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\rm X^2}=|\,\rm X|\,}}}}}}}}$$

I hope this helps. 
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.